# undefined method `total_pages' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation (Kaminari gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, kaminari

I don't understand why Kaminari is not working, I Have

> admins_controller.rb

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_admin!
    

    def index
        # Admin access to the order tables
        @orders = Order.all.page(params[:page]).per(5)
        @q = Order.ransack(params[:q])
        @orders = @q.result.order(created_at: :desc)
    end

    
end
```

> views/admins/index.html.erb

```
</table>
  
    <div class="paginator">
      <%= paginate @orders %>
    </div>
```

This above code is not at all working with kaminari and gives an error

```
`undefined method `total_pages' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Order id: 159......`
```

---

BUT, I also have another controller and index page with custom scope which works perfectly fine

> second_admins_controller.rb

```
class SecondAdminsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_admin!

    def index
        @picks = Pick.where(shop:"Sapna Xerox Near PDA College").order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(5)
        @q = Order.ransack(params[:q])
        @orders = @q.result.order(created_at: :desc)
    end
end
```

> views/second_admins/index.html.erb

```
</table>
    <div class="paginator">
      <%= paginate @picks %>
    </div>
```

This `second_admins_controller.rb` and its `index.html.erb` has pagination and it works perfectly WHEREAS The `admins_controller.rb` and its `index.html.erb` throws an error!
any solutions?
I tried looking up at other Stackoverflow solutions but non of them helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redefine `@orders` variable, so it is used without `.page(params[:page]).per(5)`

You can try this

```
def index
    # Admin access to the order tables
    @q = Order.ransack(params[:q])
    @orders = @q.result.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(5)
end
```